# Adding Labels to Links in Tree D3.js

Tags: d3.js

Hi i need to add Labels for Tree D3.js on the links without a rectangle box on mouseover. And on the rectangle I need a tooltip displaying text inside a rectangle on mouse over and also dispaly the same toolTip when mouseover on link.
Below is the d3 js of version4 I am using. Please help me with this.
I want to achieve an img like this. 
[image]

```
  let treeData,
  path;
    treeData =JSON.parse(this.traceableData);
    const treeHeight=(treeData.children.length*50);
    this.imgHeight=treeHeight;

    let children=treeData.children;
    let imghtIncrement=0;
    for(let i=0;i<children.length;i++)
    {
          if(children[i].name.length>0)
          { 
            imghtIncrement=imghtIncrement+40;

          }
    }
let rectNode = {
width: 120,
height: 17,
textMargin: 5
};

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
let margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 30, left: 160},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
let svg = d3.select(this.template.querySelector('svg.d3'))
.attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left+200)
.attr("height", this.imgHeight+imghtIncrement+100)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate("
+ margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

let i = 0,
duration = 750,
root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
let treemap = d3.tree().size([this.imgHeight+imghtIncrement, width+200]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;
//Collapse the Node and all its Children
function collapse(d) {
if (d.children) {
d.all_children = d.children;
d._children = d.children;
d._children.forEach(collapse);

d.children = null;
d.hidden = true;
}
}
root.hidden = false;
update(root);
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");


function update(source) {

let nodeHeight=15;
// Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
treeData = treemap(root);

// Compute the new tree layout.
let nodes = treeData.descendants(),
links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

// Normalize for fixed-depth.
nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 200});

// ****************** Nodes section ***************************

// Update the nodes...
let node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
.data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

// Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
let nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
.attr('class', 'node')
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
})
.on("click", click)
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
let g = d3.select(this); // The node
// The class is used to remove the additional text later
g.append('text')
    .classed('info', true)
    .attr('x', -80)
    .attr('y', -30)
    .text(d.data.objectType);
})
.on("mouseout", function() {
// Remove the info text on mouse out.
d3.select(this).select('text.info').remove()
});
// Add Circle for the nodes
nodeEnter.append('circle')
.attr('class', 'node')
.attr('r', 1e-6)
.style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
});
let rectGrpEnter = nodeEnter.append('g')
.attr('class', 'node-rect-text-grp');

rectGrpEnter.append('rect')
.attr('rx', 6)
.attr('ry', 6)
.attr('x',-120)
.attr('y',-20)
.attr('width',  rectNode.width)
.attr('height', function(d){
  let rectVariedHeight;
  if(Math.ceil(d.data.name.length/nodeHeight<1.01)){
      rectVariedHeight=40;
  }
  else
  {
      rectVariedHeight=rectNode.height*Math.ceil(d.data.name.length/nodeHeight);
  }

  return rectVariedHeight; })
.attr('fill', "white")
.style("stroke-width", 1)
.style("stroke", "black")
.attr('class', 'node-rect');
  rectGrpEnter.append("text")
  .attr("dx", function(d) {
    let x=0;
    if(Math.ceil(d.data.name.length<11)){
      x=-160;
  }
  else
  {
    x=-125;
  }
    return d.children ? x : -220;
  })
  .attr("dy", "-5")
  .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
  .on("mouseover", function() {d3.select(this).style("fill", "#0000FF");})                  
    .on("mouseout", function() {d3.select(this).style("fill", "black");})
    .on("click", function(d) { window.open(d.data.url);})
  .each(function(d) {
      let noofTextParts;
      if(d.children){  
        noofTextParts=Math.ceil(d.data.name.length/nodeHeight);
      }
      else{
        noofTextParts=Math.ceil(d.data.name.length/nodeHeight); 
      }    
// eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
for(let i=0;i<noofTextParts;i++)
{
d3.select(this).append("tspan")
.attr("dy", i ? "1.2em" : -5)
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
.attr("x", function(d2) { 
  let len;
  if(i!==0)
    {
        if(d2.children)
        {
            len=  -10;
          }
        else
        {
          len=-115;
        }
    } 
  else
    {
        len= 105;
    }
  return len;
  }
    )
.attr("class", "tspan" + i)
      .style("text-anchor", function(d3) { return d3.children ? "end" : "start"; })
    .text(function(d1) { 
      let nodeName;
      if(d1.children)
      {
        nodeName=d1.data.name.substring(i*nodeHeight,(i+1)*nodeHeight);} 

    else
    {
      nodeName= d1.data.name.substring(i*nodeHeight,(i+1)*nodeHeight);
    }
    return nodeName;
    });
  }

  });

// UPDATE
let nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

// Transition to the proper position for the node
nodeUpdate.transition()
.duration(duration)
.attr("transform", function(d) { 
  return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
});
let circleRadius = 0;
// Update the node attributes and style
nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
.attr('r', circleRadius)
.style("fill", function(d) {
  return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
})
.attr('cursor', 'pointer');

// Remove any exiting nodes
let nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
.duration(duration)
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
})
.remove();

// On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
nodeExit.select('circle')
.attr('r', 1e-6);

// On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
nodeExit.select('text')
.style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

// ****************** links section ***************************

// Update the links...
let link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
.data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
let linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
.attr("class", "link")
.attr('d', function(d){
  console.log(d);
  let o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
  return diagonal(o, o)
});

// UPDATE
let linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

// Transition back to the parent element position
linkUpdate.transition()
.duration(duration)
.attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });


// Remove any exiting links
let linkExit = link.exit().transition()
.duration(duration)
.attr('d', function(d) {
  console.log(d);
  let o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
  return diagonal(o, o)
})
.remove();
console.log(linkExit);

// Store the old positions for transition.
nodes.forEach(function(d){
d.x0 = d.x;
d.y0 = d.y;
});

// Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
function diagonal(s, d) {

path = `M ${s.y- (rectNode.width + circleRadius) } ${s.x}
      C ${(s.y- (rectNode.width + circleRadius)  + d.y ) / 2} ${s.x},
        ${(s.y- (rectNode.width + circleRadius)  + d.y ) / 2} ${d.x},
        ${d.y } ${d.x}`

return path
}
}

if(root.hasOwnProperty("children"))
//Only children will be collpased
{
  root.children.forEach(collapse);
}
// To collapse all to root element
collapse(root);

//Changes added for collapsing ends
update(root);

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
if (d.children) {
d._children = d.children;
d.children = null;
if (d._children) {
    d._children.forEach(function(n) { n.hidden = true; });

    if (d.parent) {
        d.parent.children = d.parent.all_children;
        d.parent.children.forEach(function(n) {
            n.hidden = false;
        });
    }
}
} else {
d.children = d._children;
d._children = null;
if (d.children) {
    d.children.forEach(function(n) { n.hidden = false; });
    if (d.parent) {
        d.parent.children = [d,];
        d.parent.children.filter(function(n) { return n !== d; }).forEach(function(n) {
            n.hidden = true;
        });
    }
}
}
update(d);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have added labels to the links.

Hope it helps you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
    .node circle {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 3px;
    }

    .node text {
        font: 12px sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .link path {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .link text {
        font: 12px sans-serif;
        stroke: #333;
        stroke-width: 1;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <!-- load the d3.js library -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var treeData =
        {
            "name": "Top Level",
            "linkname": "null",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Level 2: A",
                    "linkname": "Link_1",
                    "children": [
                        { "name": "Son of A", "linkname": "Link_2.1" },
                        { "name": "Daughter of A", "linkname": "Link_2.2" }
                    ]
                },
                { "name": "Level 2: B", "linkname": "Link_3", }
            ]
        };

        // Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
        var margin = { top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90 },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // append the svg object to the body of the page
        // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
        // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate("
                + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var i = 0,
            duration = 750,
            root;

        // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
        var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

        // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
        root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function (d) { return d.children; });
        root.x0 = height / 2;
        root.y0 = 0;

        // Collapse after the second level
        root.children.forEach(collapse);

        update(root);

        // Collapse the node and all it's children
        function collapse(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children
                d._children.forEach(collapse)
                d.children = null
            }
        }

        function update(source) {

            // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
            var treeData = treemap(root);

            // Compute the new tree layout.
            var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
                links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

            // Normalize for fixed-depth.
            nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                d.y = d.depth * 180
            });

            // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

            // Update the nodes...
            var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
                .data(nodes, function (d) {
                    return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                });

            // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
                .attr('class', 'node')
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                })
                .on('click', click);

            // Add Circle for the nodes
            nodeEnter.filter(function (d) {
                return (!d.data.type || d.data.type !== 'data');
            }).append('circle')
                .attr('class', 'node')
                .attr('r', 1e-6)
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                });

            nodeEnter.filter(function (d) {
                return (d.data.type && d.data.type === 'data');
            }).append('rect')
                .attr('class', 'node')
                .attr('width', 20)
                .attr('height', 20)
                .attr('y', -10)
                .attr('x', -10)
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                });

            // Add labels for the nodes
            nodeEnter.append('text')
                .attr("dy", "2em")
                .attr("x", function (d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? 13 : 13;
                })
                .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? "start" : "start";
                })
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.data.name;
                });

            // UPDATE
            var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

            // Transition to the proper position for the node
            nodeUpdate.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                });

            // Update the node attributes and style
            nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
                .attr('r', 10)
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                })
                .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


            // Remove any exiting nodes
            var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
                })
                .remove();

            // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
            nodeExit.select('circle')
                .attr('r', 1e-6);

            // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
            nodeExit.select('text')
                .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

            // ****************** links section ***************************

            // Update the links...
            var link = svg.selectAll('g.link')
                .data(links, function (d) {
                    return d.id;
                });

            // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
            var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('g', 'g')
                .attr("class", "link");

            linkEnter.append('text')
                .attr("class","linkLabels")
                .text(function (d, i) {
                    if (d.parent && d.parent.children.length > 1) {
                        if (!d.parent.index) d.parent.index = 0;
                        return d.data.linkname;
                    }
                })
                .attr("opacity",0)
                .attr('dy', "-1em");

            linkEnter.append('path')
                .attr('d', function (d) {
                    var o = {
                        x: source.x0,
                        y: source.y0
                    }
                    return diagonal(o, o)
                })
                .on("mouseover", function(){
                    d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text").attr("opacity",1);
                })
                .on("mouseleave", function(){
                    d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text").attr("opacity",0);
                })


            // UPDATE
            var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

            // Transition back to the parent element position
            linkUpdate.select('path').transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr('d', function (d) {
                    return diagonal(d, d.parent)
                });

            linkUpdate.select('text').transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr('transform', function (d) {
                    if (d.parent) {
                        return 'translate(' + ((d.parent.y + d.y) / 2) + ',' + ((d.parent.x + d.x) / 2) + ')'
                    }
                })

            // Remove any exiting links
            link.exit().each(function (d) {
                d.parent.index = 0;
            })

            var linkExit = link.exit()
                .transition()
                .duration(duration);

            linkExit.select('path')
                .attr('d', function (d) {
                    var o = {
                        x: source.x,
                        y: source.y
                    }
                    return diagonal(o, o)
                })

            linkExit.select('text')
                .style('opacity', 0);

            linkExit.remove();

            // Store the old positions for transition.
            nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                d.x0 = d.x;
                d.y0 = d.y;
            });

            // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
            function diagonal(s, d) {
                path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
                        C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
                            ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
                            ${d.y} ${d.x}`
                return path
            }

            // Toggle children on click.
            function click(d) {
                if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
                } else {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d._children = null;
                }
                update(d);
            }
        }


    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks  can you please make this label of link to display as a tooltip during on mouseover on link

Comment: I have edited the above code and made changes to show the label on mouse over. Please check if this is what you need.

Comment: You want me to add tooltip to the links in treemap layout having rect's above in your question?

Comment: You can refer this link: https://bl.ocks.org/swayvil/b86f8d4941bdfcbfff8f69619cd2f460.... Let me know if its useful to you...

Comment: hi is it possible to have link between two dublkicate children